# How to send FormData to an action in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, payment-gateway

In my site, visitor can visit site & can place order.

Now,first I insert the details into DB & then call a PaymentGateway api for transaction.

I have created FormData as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/MyController/MyAction/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'MyVariable': objData
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data!="Error") {
            var payment = data;
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('key', gtKFFx);
            formData.append('tsnId', payment.TransantionId);
            formData.append('amount', billAmount);
            formData.append('productinfo', 'Test');
            formData.append('firstname', custName);
            formData.append('email', 'chetan.gupta21@gmail.com');
            formData.append('surl', 'http://google.com');
            formData.append('furl', 'http://facebook.com');
            formData.append('hash', payment.TransactionHash);
            $('#frmPayment').submit(function(e) {
                // How do I send formData from here
            });
      } else {

      }
    },
    error: function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
  <form action="http://thirdpartyurl" method="post" id="frmPayment">
  </form>
```

### My question how do I send the formdata using jQuery submit method in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using  $('#frmPayment').submit(function(e) , you can use Jquery form plugins like ajaxForm , ajaxSubmit.This two plugins specially for submitting the form with AJAX using jquery.The code might look like this,

```
        $('#frmPayment').ajaxForm({url:'http://thirdpartyur',type:'post'}),
        $("#frmPayment").ajaxSubmit({url: 'http://thirdpartyur', type: 'post'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that mostly depends on the instructions that the payment gateway provider's api provides. But basically doing a regular form submit will do a post with all serialized data inside the form (inside a form element) to the specified url.